# How to achieve text overprint and graphics knockout with minimal settings?

Tags: colorspace

While passing an illustrated pdftex PDF (TeX Live 2018) through Acrobat Pro's (v11) *Sheetfed CMYK* preflight profile, to get it ready for prepress, I came across warnings about black text smaller than 12pt that was set to knock out. The warnings covered practically the entire text.

Some research brought me, on the one hand, to Ghent Workgroup's 1v4 specifications which state (2.3.12)

> Black text smaller than or equal to 12 points should not be set to knock-out. Grayscale objects should not be set to overprint. White text shall not be set to overprint. White line-art should not be set to overprint.

and on the other, to the ctan.org package `colorspace` which, among other things, provides for overprinting.

When I use `\usepackage[overprint]{colorspace}` the above warnings disappear, but another batch of warnings emerge about grayscale objects set to overprint.

But when I use instead `\usepackage[knockout]{colorspace}` and envelope text instances in `\textoverprint{<text>}` both text and graphics pass the preflight test.

Of course, in a book-lenghth set of files, with footnotes, endnotes, bibliography and the intricacies of `memoir` it is not an easy task to hunt down all instances of text and wrap them in `\textoverprint{<text>}`.

So, is there a global way to achieve the required overprint for text and knockout for graphics, with `colorspace` or otherwise, without having to resort to a hunt for all text, or some other similarly time-consuming effort?

**Update**
The following MWE makes a PDF which passes the Acrobat Pro's preflight profile mentioned above, with the exception of PDF/X related issues (for these see package `pdfx`).

It shows the extend of intervention needed to cover all possible text items. It would be easier if the preamble could have `\usepackage[overprint]{colorspace}` and then in the body a command could exempt graphics, like `\graphicsoverprint[0]{<graphic>}`, but `colorpace`'s manual states it takes care of "text and line-art only, not external images."

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside,openany,final]{memoir}

\pdfminorversion=3
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[knockout]{colorspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% memoir's footnote marker
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\textoverprint[1]{\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}}}
\makeatother

% memoir's footmark
\footmarkstyle{\textoverprint[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}}

% memoir's pagenumber
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{\textoverprint[1]{\thepage}}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\textoverprint[1]{\thepage}}{}

\begin{document}
\textoverprint[1]{\chapter*{Chapter 1}}
\textoverprint[1]{Some text, with some note.}%
\footnote{\textoverprint[1]{A footnote.}}

% provide a vectorgray.pdf file and uncomment the lines below; to pass the
% preflight it will have to be grayscale. No \textoverprint{} here.
%\begin{figure}[ht]
%  \includegraphics[width=100pt]{./vectorgray.pdf}
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide a complete code for a minimal example which demonstrates the problem?